# How to approximate percentile value from value-count map?

Tags: algorithms

Background: [How Percentile Approximation Works (and Why It’s More Useful Than Averages)](https://www.timescale.com/blog/how-percentile-approximation-works-and-why-its-more-useful-than-averages/)

In traditional scenario, we store each value in an array/slice, in that case, we can just sort the array, and get the approximate percentile. For example,

```
[67, 68, 70, 71, 76, 78, 78, 79, 80, 98]
```

We could get the p90(90th percentiles)  is `80`, by

1. Get the `length` of the array, which is `10`
2. Calculate the `index` by `int(length * 0.9)`, which is `9`
3. Return the index data `return arr[index-1]`, which is `80`

In my specific case, I have a `sync.Map`, and the data looks like:

```
{67:5 , 68:8, 70:20:, 71:10, 76:80, 78:120, 79:90, 80:73, 98:2}
```

We can interpret that by saying: there are 5 people got a score of 67 and so on.

Just wondering if there's any exists algorithm to calculate the approximate percentile value in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the prefix sum of the counts,

```
67:5, 68:13, 70: 33, 71: 43, 76: 123, 78: 243, 79: 333, 80: 406, 98: 408
```

and find the value corresponding to `90%` of `408` = `367.2`. (Between `79` and `80`.)

[image]